# Trying to loop through database with bootstrap cards

Tags: php, html, database

Trying to loop through my database and to post a bootstrap card for each "board member" in my database. However, with my current code, they post on top of each other, and I need them in rows. Here is my current code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 my-4">
    @if(count($boardMembers) > 0)
        @foreach($boardMembers as $boardMember)
        <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/user1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{$boardMember->name}}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text">{!!$boardMember->description!!}</p>
                </div>        
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
            <p>No Members Found</p>
    @endif
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to loop the "col" not the "card"

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop the `.col` part:

```
@if(count($boardMembers) > 0)
    @foreach($boardMembers as $boardMember)
<div class="col-sm-4 my-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img/user1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">{{$boardMember->name}}</h2>
            <p class="card-text">{!!$boardMember->description!!}</p>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
    @endforeach
@else
<p>No Members Found</p>
@endif
```

This will create multiple `.col`s with `.card`s but make sure you style the `<p>No Members Found</p>` or you can make it inside a `.col` too

Comment: They are still just in a column, but I added a row div to the whole thing and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes you have to, in your original code you already have the `.row` in your original code that's not why I didn't mention it.